# I can not have the Permission ''sudo" to execute command lines on putty!

Tags: sudo

I have a problem for permission using "sudo" on putty (connected to raspberry pi3).

My usrname is: karim
My password: 0000
Each time, I have got this error when executing a command line " karim is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported"

What should I do to execute any command line as adminstrator in this case? 
Waiting your helps!!
Have a grat day!!!

Answer (score 1):

Login as pi.

Copy /etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd as 011-karim-nopasswd. Edit that and change pi to karim. You will need to use sudo for that.

Logout.

Login as karim.

Test whether sudo works for you.

Later you can remove the 010_pi-nopasswd file to disable sudo for pi.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but the problem is not resolved yet!!!! is there any other suggestion ????

Comment: Add your karim userid to the groups that pi is in.

Answer (score 1):

By default **sudo** on Raspbian is configured that a user being in group `sudo` can use it. So check if *karim* is in group `sudo` with:

```
karim@raspberrypi ~$ groups
```

If group `sudo` is not shown then you have to add *karim* to this group. The problem  is that you have to be in group `sudo` to do it ...

Because user *pi* is in this group you have to logout from *karim* and login as user *pi*. Then execute this command:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~$ sudo adduser karim sudo
```

Logout and login as *karim* and things should go.